# How to style date input field separately

Tags: javascript, css

I want to style each field of the date separately, for example:

html

```
<label for="start">Start month:</label>

<input type="month" id="start" name="start"
       min="2018-03" value="2018-05">
```

css

```
day {
border: 1px solid blue;
}

month {
border: 1px solid red;
}

year {
border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

How is this achievable with one input field only for the date using css?

Comment: So use an attribute selector, not an element selector `[type="month"] { }`

Comment: the input is only one and the type is `month`. Are you suggesting I need to create an input field for each of them ( ie : day,month,year = 3 input fields). I need the date picker so I am unale to do so.

Comment: there is the vendor specific styles like `webkit-datetime-edit-month-field` but dont know if there are other browsers that support those or similar, otherwise yes you would need three separate fields to get individual styles